# Existence of an equivalent norm on a normed space

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, operator-theory, normed-spaces

Let $L$ be a normed space with norm $\|\cdot\|_1: L\to \mathbf{R}$.
Let $T$ be a linear invertible operator on $L$ such that $\frac 1 c \|x\|_1<\|T^n x\|_1 < c \|x\|_1$ for all $x\in L\setminus \{0\}$ and $n\in \mathbf{N}$.
Show that there is a norm $\|\cdot\|_2: L\to \mathbf{R}$ equivalent to norm $\|\cdot\|_1$ such that $\| Tx\|_2=\|x\|_2$ for all $x\in L$.

My thought is to consider $\|\cdot\|_2: L\to \mathbf{R}$ such that

$\|x\|_2=\|x\|_1 + \sup_{n\in \mathbf{N}} \|T^n x\|_1$

I have proven equivalence of the two norms but I am finding it uneasy proving that $\| Tx\|_2=\|x\|_2$.

Any help would be appreciated. Would my norm work?
Thanks

Comment: I am afraid your idea does not work. With $T=\frac12 I$, you have that $$\lVert Tx\rVert_2 = \lVert x \rVert_1, $$ while $\lVert x \rVert_2=\frac32\lVert x\rVert_1$.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro That's true, what if I consider $\|x\|_2 = \sup_{n\in \mathbf{N}} \|T^n x\|_1$?

Comment: Then my previous example yields $\lVert Tx\rVert_2 =\frac12 \lVert x\rVert_2$, I am afraid.

Comment: $T^{-1}$ is also bounded:  did you try $\|x\|_2 = \sup_{n \in \mathbf Z} \|T^n x\|_1$? This gives you the equality $\|Tx\|_2 = \|x\|_2$ immediately.

Comment: What about $\limsup_n \|T^n x\|$? This would work even if $T$ is not necessarily surjective.

Comment: My previous example is not correct. If $T=\frac12 I$ then $T^n$ is not bounded below. However, UmbertoP's idea seems very promising.